# crontab script schecking continously (24 * 7)

Tags: linux, bash

**Inside crontab -e , i have added this entry**

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/memcached_autostart.sh
```

**And inside /usr/bin  i have the script named memcached_autostart.sh**

**/usr/bin memcached_autostart.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
ps -eaf | grep 11211 | grep memcached
# if not found - equals to 1, start it
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
memcached -d -m 16 -p 11211 -u nobody
else
echo "eq 0 - memcache running - do nothing"
fi
```

When i tested this manually this way

**Started the Memcache**

```
memcached -d -m 16 -p 11211 -u nobody
ps -eaf | grep 11211 | grep memcached
nobody     611     1  0 13:28 ?        00:00:00 memcached -d -m 16 -p 11211 -u nobody
```

**Then killed the process**

```
kill -9 611
```

I was expecting that the crontab automatically starts the Memcache if its down , but it is not starting the Memcache , please tell me if i am doing anything wrong .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [if your crontab is working](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/%2absd-17/crontab-test-550745/)

After test it, The [shell exit can be greater than 1](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/shell-how-to-determine-the-exit-status-of-linux-and-unix-command/), so try to change for this:

```
if [ $? -ge 1 ]
```

Comment: And it could be just `if ps -eaf | grep 11211 | grep memcached; then`

Comment: [See this post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/*bsd-17/crontab-test-550745/). It could help you

Answer (score 1):

First your cron:

In the title of this, you're talking about *every 24 hours*. For this, you have
to spécify at which moment of day in the two first fields:

```
1 2 * * * doTheJob
```

So every `day of month`, every `month` and every `day of week`, at 2hour 1 minute , the script will be run

Better is to put your script in `/etc/cron.daily`.

Now for the job, did you try:

```
ps -C memcached

ps -C memcached ho pid

echo $?
```

If there is no `memcached` pid, (ie: no answer), `$?` must be not null.

So maybe:

```
ps -C memcached >/dev/null || memcached -d -m 16 -p 11211 -u nobody
```

This could be out of a script, simply in your crontab:

```
1 2 * * * ps -C memcached >/dev/null || memcached -d -m 16 -p 11211 -u nobody
```

(nota: if you use system crontab: `/etc/cron.d/myJob` or `/etc/crontab`, instead of user's (root) crontab, you have to spécify userlevel as 6th field:

```
1 2 * * * root ps -C memcached >/dev/null || memcached -d -m 16 -p 11211 -u nobody
```

)

Comment: Thanks , you misunderstood my question or may be i was wrong , i meant 24*7 avialibility

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add your own things under `/usr/local/` not `/usr/` (which is managed by your package mechanism).

Then your [crontab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) entry

```
  * * * * * /usr/bin/memcached_autostart.sh
```

is running every minute. Are you sure you want to run it that often? I would run it every 5 or 10 minutes (and I am not even sure it is really useful, because `memcached` is a well debugged daemon which crashes very rarely).

At last, I would suggest to add logging messages with `logger` into your `/usr/local/bin/memcached_autostart.sh` script (and be sure to make it executable with `chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/memcached_autostart.sh` for instance).

To query the process table, you could use `pidof` or `pgrep`; if you just want to know what process is listening port 11211 use `netstat -p`

Comment: I have been given a Linux (ubuntu ) on which memcached is present in /usr/bin , so cant ask them to do it in local folder .
This runs under production so want to be on safe side to check for every minute
I have chnaged chmod to 777 for that script  chmod 777 memcached_autostart.sh
But still its not running , please suggest

Comment: Yes `memcached` is given thru a package so is in `/usr/bin`; but *your script* `memcached_autostart.sh` should be in `/usr/local/bin` and you should add `logger` commands in it (at least during the debugging phase). Be sure that `cron` is running! Look into log files uder `/var/log`